# Why gives error? - npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular

While installing angular some error shows on command prompt : npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ta.2":{"name":"@angul'

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is following: run below commands on CLI -
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest